# Is there a way to get line-by-line console output and print it in a separate script?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, output, stdout

In a script that runs a discord bot, I'd like to run other scripts when the user requests it (like `/script2`) and print line by line the console output that this called script is outputting, sending a new discord message with the contents every time there's a new output.

So far I've made the script recognize when the user wants to run a command by searching for the "/" at the start, but am having trouble finding the right way to run the requested script from within another program, and sending the console output in the discord channel.

Does anyone know how to help?

Source Code

```
import discord
from subprocess import run        #As of right now i'm using run to run the script, but it is simply the easiest way I managed to do it in.

TOKEN = 'TOKEN(Removed for the post)'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  username = str(message.author).split("#")[0]
  usermsg = str(message.content)
  channel = str(message.channel.name)
  print(f'{username}, {usermsg}, {channel}')

if message.author == client.user:
    return

if message.channel.name == "test":
    if usermsg.startswith("/"):
        await message.channel.send(f'Executing your requested script, {username}')
        arg = str(usermsg[1:len(usermsg)])
        result = run(["python3", "Path/to/script", arg], capture_output=True)
        output = result.stdout  # At the moment, the second script doesn't output anything on the console, which is also not what I want. I would love if you could get both console output and send line-by-line output to discord, although I could live with the output only being sent to the discord channel.
        print(output)
        await message.channel.send(output)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: So, essentially, your question is: "How to redirect `stdout` and send it to discord"?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I guess so? Anywhere you can point me towards in order to know how to do it?

Comment: I'd be great if you could add some code, it's really hard to point you in the right direction without any context

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński On it. Give me a second

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Here. Added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no attribute as `result.output`, the attribute you're looking for is `stdout`, this however returns a bytes sequence, you can decode it to convert it to a string:

```py
import sys

result = run([sys.executable, "Path/to/script", arg], capture_output=True)
output = result.stdout.decode("utf-8")
print(output)
```

Comment: When I change it to sys.executable, it gives me this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sys.executable'

Comment: It's not a string, use it as a variable (remember to import `sys` though)

Comment: Of course... now it works. I am assuming I can't ptint the output as it comes in, right?

Comment: No, not really. You could however import the function(s) from the other file and simply send a message within the function itself.